# Finding users in local network, via rwho

Tags: networking, permissions, users, remote, username

I want to get the usernames of all the users currently logged in my network. I found out the command 'rwho', which does the job, but the username is cut, with only 8 letters, and I didn't found a way to display the full username.

Is there a way to do this? Or a different way that I can see which users are logged in the local network?

If there's a way to display a list of complete username of all users, there's a way to check if a user (with a given username) is currently logged?

Thanks

Comment: try `w` command see if it helps you.

Comment: Also look at `who` and for more options try `man who`.

Comment: The who command doesn't work, as I can only see users in a given computer. I want to check users in all the LAN, not just in one computer of the network.

Comment: Using `nmap -s[P|n] 192.168.10.0/24` should show _host and ip add_ but will be frowned on if you don't have the authority to do this on the network .

Comment: I've tried it, it show the hosts, but not the logged in users. I can have, for instance, all of the hosts online, but no user logged in.